# Try the first rule if the second rule fails

Tags: parsing, ocaml, ocamlyacc

I have defined two sets of identifiers `IDENTIFIER_ONE` and `IDENTIFIER_TWO` which are both exculsive subsets of `IDENTIFIER`. I would like to write a parser such that:

```
"i1(arg) EOS" can't be parsed (1)
"i2(arg) EOS" can be parsed (2)
"i1(arg) = value EOS" can be parsed (3)
"i2(arg) = value EOS" can be parsed (4)
```

where `i1`(resp., `i2`) belongs to `IDENTIFIER_ONE` (resp., `IDENTIFIER_TWO`); `arg` and `value` belong to `IDENTIFIER`. The following `parser.mly` has already realized all the points I am after, except `(4)`:

```
identifier:
| IDENTIFIER_ONE { $1 }
| IDENTIFIER_TWO { $1 } 

block_statement_EOS:
| identifier LPAREN identifier RPAREN EQUAL identifier EOS { BSE_Let ($1, $3, $6) }
| IDENTIFIER_TWO LPAREN identifier RPAREN EOS { BSE_I_I ($1, $3) }
```

Given `i1(arg) = value EOS` as input, as goal `(3)` it is correctly read as `BSE_Let (i1, arg, value)`. However, given `i2(arg) = value EOS` as input, it stops the parsing after reading `EQUAL`. I guess it is because once the parse meets `i2(arg)`, it goes to the 2nd rule of `block_statement_EOS`, and later `EQUAL` can't be parsed.

Ideally, I would hope the parser could try the 1st rule of `block_statement_EOS` if the 2nd rule fails. Could anyone help me to make this possible?

**PS**: If I write the `parser.mly` as follows, all the goals can be achieved. Does anyone know why? Additionally I really don't like this workaround, because I do need to write `identifier` instead of two subsets in many other rules, I would hope a more elegant solution...

```
block_statement_EOS:
| IDENTIFIER_ONE LPAREN identifier RPAREN EQUAL identifier EOS { BSE_Let ($1, $3, $6) }
| IDENTIFIER_TWO LPAREN identifier RPAREN EQUAL identifier EOS { BSE_Let ($1, $3, $6) }
| IDENTIFIER_TWO LPAREN identifier RPAREN EOS { BSE_I_I ($1, $3) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your parser encounters an `LPAREN` after an `IDENTIFIER_TWO`, it has to decide whether to shift or to reduce:

- shift: put `LPAREN` on the stack;
- reduce: replace `IDENTIFIER_TWO`, which is on top of the stack, by `identifier`.

If your parser chooses to shift, it will never reduce this particular `IDENTIFIER_TWO` into `identifier` (because this particular `IDENTIFIER_TWO` will never be on top of the stack again), meaning that it will always reduce the second rule of `block_statement_EOS`.

If your parser chooses to reduce, it will never reduce the second rule of `block_statement_EOS`, as this rule starts with `IDENTIFIER_TWO` and not `identifier`.

This is why your second version works, because there is no need to choose between shifting and reducing after `IDENTIFIER_TWO`. The choice is made later, if you wish.

Comment: Thank you... Let's still take `i2(arg) = value EOS` as example, does it mean that the parser chooses `shift` when it encounters an `LPAREN`? It is a pity that the parser could not try another choice (`reduce`) if one choice (`shift`) leads to fail... Is there another way to work around, except my second version which I don't like?

Comment: All symbols are shifted (i.e. put on the stack) at some point. Shifting basically means: reading the next symbol. What you want would imply backtracking, which is potentially very inefficient. However, it is possible that other parsing technologies would work, but I'm not familiar with them. Take a look at Menhir, maybe it can handle this case better.